# Need help with passing parameters to a launch file

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, parameters, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to over ride rtabmap parameters on a rosrun command line....I want to used the unaltered rtabmap launch file overriding some of the Grid parameters. Can this be done from the command line? If not is there a way to call rtabmap with include from another launch file and do this I do not want to cop and modify the launch file.  I can not seem to get any solution on this. Thank you for your time.

The below code does not work.

```
roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" depth_topic:=/zed/depth/depth_registered frame_id:=base_frame approx_sync:=false visual_odometry:=false odom_topic:=/zed/odom camera_info_topic:=/zed/rgb/camera_info rgb_topic:=/zed/rgb/image_rect_color  rtabmapviz:=false Grid/MaxGroundAngle:=45.0 Grid/MaxObstacleHeight:=2.0
```

I tried setting inside a launch file:

```
<!-- rosparam command = "load" file = "$(find my_package)/example.yaml" / -->  
<param name = "/rtabmap/Mem/IncrementalMemory" type = "bool" value = "false" />  
<param name = "/Mem/IncrementalMemory" type = "bool" value = "false" /> 
      
<include file="$(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/rtabmap.launch"/>

<param name = "/rtabmap/Mem/IncrementalMemory" type = "bool" value = "false" />  
<param name = "/Mem/IncrementalMemory" type = "bool" value = "false" />
```

But the rtabmap keeps setting values to true.

```
[ INFO] [1529896284.763605800]: Setting RTAB-Map parameter "Mem/IncrementalMemory"="true"
[ INFO] [1529896284.764360510]: Setting RTAB-Map parameter "Mem/InitWMWithAllNodes"="false"
```

even though

```
rosparam list | grep Incr

/Mem/IncrementalMemory
/rtabmap/Kp/IncrementalDictionary
/rtabmap/Kp/IncrementalFlann
/rtabmap/Mem/IncrementalMemory
/rtabmap/rtabmap/Mem/IncrementalMemory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295179/need-help-with-passing-parameters-to-a-launch-file./) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2018-06-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-24**:\

> The below code does not work

What does this mean?

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2018-06-24**:
it does not alter the values of the parameters ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seams that you are setting parameters in the wrong name-space for your node.

If you look at [launch file of rtabmap](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/rtabmap.launch#L247) you can see that parameters are set depending on `localization` parameter and it seams they should not be used by the user.

Also you are setting `bool` parameters, but they are actually strings.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2018-06-25**:
thanks .... what I was looking for I just found rtabmap.ini  still don't know how to over ride parameters   on input but this works for me.   Yes I totally missed the the fact that the Men parameters was controlled by localization ....